# What is the largest Instant that can be represented as millis since epoch?

Tags: java-time

`Instant.MAX.toEpochMilli()` raises `java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow`.

What is the largest timestamp representable without hitting the limit of long?

And is there a constant somewhere for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest timestamp that won't raise an exception in `toEpochMilli()` is **`+292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z`**.

`Instant.MAX` is much larger `+1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z`

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MAX_VALUE); // +292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z
```

I'm not aware of any constant for this specific date but it's easy enough to compute with `Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MAX_VALUE))`

Comment: Okay, but is this useful knowledge? Moments in real life are not so far in the future so I have difficulties to see the practical relevance. And IMHO we should not model infinite future as maximum supported instant. It does not feel clean.

Comment: Well, many times you need to initialize a variable with the max value. For example when you need to do `min(currentValue, previousValue)` then you want to initialize the very first  `previousValue` with the max possible value. In my case I was using `Instant.MAX` and then it blow up in some other part of the code when trying to `.toEpochMilli()` , I had to figure out what was really a safe max value when dealing with Instant that will be converted to millis, that's why I wrote it here.

Comment: @MenoHochschild , when you said  "we should not model infinite future as maximum supported instant" I realized that in fact it would be nice to have some other concept to represent a timestamp that it's after any other moment in time . But is there really anything that represent "infinite future" in `java.time.*` or any other time library ?

Comment: Not in `java.time` where you even have to cope with different maximum values dependent on the type you work with. With regards to my lib Time4J, I have modelled infinite time intervals by defining a [Boundary-class](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/Boundary.html). This approach might give you an idea. We could also define a comparable wrapper around `Instant`.

Comment: Interestnig discussion. It seems there is a follow-up question: [Is there any way to represent infinite future / end of time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808516/is-there-any-way-to-represent-infinite-future-end-of-time-in-java)