# Is there any way to represent infinite future / end of time in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Until now I've been using `Instant.MAX` to mean infinite future or end of time. For example when calculating the minimum timestamp of a collection of timestamps:

```
Iterator<Instant> it = ....

Instant minTs = Instant.MAX;
while(it.hasNext()) {
  Instant curr = it.next();
  minTs = curr.isBefore(minTs) ? curr : minTs; 
}
```

But I realized that there are several issues with using `Instant.MAX` to represent "infinite future":

- `Instant.MAX` is not the same as `OffsetDateTime.MAX`
- `Instant.MAX.toEpochMilli()` raises `ArithmeticException: long overflow`, so sometimes I use `Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MAX_VALUE)` instead of `Instant.MAX` which is not very intent-revealing.
- ...

So I wonder, if there is a better way to represent the end of time in `java.time.*` or in other alternative java time library?

Answer (score 3):

We've always used a placeholder, one that works in sql, java, and whatever other programming language that's relevant. The placeholder is selected to be interoperable and to avoid annoying issues like:

> `Instant.MAX.toEpochMilli()` raises `ArithmeticException`

`9999-12-31 00:00:00Z` is what we use. It's small enough to fit in all the `java.time` types and also in `java.sql.Timestamp` (though watch out for time zone issues). And it's big enough to effectively represent "forever". You, me, and everyone we know will be long dead before `9999-12-31 00:00:00Z` is considered "soon".

> For example when calculating the minimum timestamp of a collection of timestamps

For this specific use case, you don't need a "max":

```
Instant findMin(Iterator<Instant> iter) {
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        return null;
    }

    Instant minTs = iter.next();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Instant curr = iter.next();

        minTs = ...;
    }

    return minTs;
}
```

Not sure if this use case is a real one or just something used to illustrate the problem.